How to convert an image url to File object from Google oAuth response?
In my React project I have a google oAuth API which I'm retrieving the google image url from the response:
const userInfoResponse = await axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo', {
   headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${googleResponse.access_token}` }
});

const google_image = userInfoResponse.data.picture;
console.log(google_image);
//https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocKjThtaGf5USLuL2LBMBuYxfDG0gDdM-RLA_I__UvNI3p_2Hlk=s96-c

Now I want to convert this URL to a File Object. So i tried to first convert this to a blob and then use the blob to construct a File but is not working as expected!
const googleImageResponse = await fetch(google_image);
const blob = await googleImageResponse.blob();
const googleImageFile = new File([blob], "profileAvatar.png");
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('profile', googleImageFile);
formData.append('record', userResponse.data.id);

But in the above code the blob type is text/html and not an image. So when I'm adding the File to the FormData is failing to render it because the image is not of image type.

Required Solution:
I want to be able to:

Get Image URL from Google Response (e.g. https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocKjThtaGf5USLuL2LBMBuYxfDG0gDdM-RLA_I__UvNI3p_2Hlk=s96-c)
Convert Image URL to File
Pass File to FormData
Pass FormData toan API!


Maybe it helps to add the MIME Type explicity in the options param of the File constructor.

Cool! That actually worked!
Here is the line i changed you can create an answer so we can close this question! const googleImageFile = new File([blob], "profileAvatar.png", { type: blob.type || 'image/png' });

Add the MIME type explicitly by using the options parameter in the File constructor.
const googleImageFile = new File([blob], 'profileAvatar.png', {
  type: blob.type || 'image/png'
});


INTERACTIVE SOLUTION BASED ON @Emiel's Reply


const getFormData = async(url) => {
  const googleImageResponse = await fetch(url);
  const blob = await googleImageResponse.blob();

  //FIX HERE
  const googleImageFile = new File([blob], 'profileAvatar.png', {
    type: blob.type || 'image/png'
  });
  //END OF FIX

  const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(googleImageFile);
  document.getElementById("myImg").src = imageURL;
  document.getElementById("imgName").textContent = googleImageFile.name;
};


//BUTTON EVENT
document.getElementById("loadImageButton").addEventListener("click", async() => {
  const url = document.getElementById("imageUrlInput").value;
  await getFormData(url);
});
#myImg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
<input type="text" id="imageUrlInput" value="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocKjThtaGf5USLuL2LBMBuYxfDG0gDdM-RLA_I__UvNI3p_2Hlk=s96-c" placeholder="Enter image URL" />
<button id="loadImageButton">Load Image</button>

<p id="imgName"></p>
<img id="myImg" />



